# Css animation not work on Chrome

Tags: html, css

i was work on this animation http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/dIomg

and its work with me only on firefox but not chrome , Here the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
body { background-color: #111111; }
div {
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
  color: red;
}
div p { margin:0; }
#error:hover { text-shadow: 0 0 200px #ffffff,0 0 80px #008000,0 0 6px #0000ff; }
#code:hover { text-shadow: 0 0 100px red,0 0 40px FireBrick,0 0 8px DarkRed; }
#error {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px #ffffff,0 0 30px #008000,0 0 6px #0000ff;
}
#error span {
  animation: upper 11s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: upper 11s linear infinite;
}
#code span:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation: lower 10s linear infinite;
     -webkit-animation: lower 10s linear infinite;
}
#code span:nth-of-type(1) {
  text-shadow: none;
  opacity:.4;
}
@keyframes upper {
  0%,19.999%,22%,62.999%,64%, 64.999%,70%,100% {
    opacity:.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px #ffffff,0 0 30px #008000,0 0 6px #0000ff;
  }
  20%,21.999%,63%,63.999%,65%,69.999% {
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}
@keyframes lower {
  0%,12%,18.999%,23%,31.999%,37%,44.999%,46%,49.999%,51%,58.999%,61%,68.999%,71%,85.999%,96%,100% {
    opacity:0.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
  }
  19%,22.99%,32%,36.999%,45%,45.999%,50%,50.99%,59%,60.999%,69%,70.999%,86%,95.999% { 
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <p id="error">E<span>r</span>ror</p>
  <p id="code">4<span>0</span><span>4</span></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestion please ?? i try to add to the animation code -webkit-animation but its still not work on chrome

Comment: your codepen works the same way for me both in chrome and firefox can you be more specific in what is not working.

Comment: the code pen work but the code i write not

Comment: you mean to say the the same code not works for you when you integrate it along with your code.

Comment: Yes Exactly its not work with me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a `-webkit-` prefixed version of your animations for Chrome..

```
#error span {
  -webkit-animation: upper 11s linear infinite;
  animation: upper 11s linear infinite;
}
#code span:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: lower 10s linear infinite;
  animation: lower 10s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upper {
  0%,19.999%,22%,62.999%,64%, 64.999%,70%,100% {
    opacity:.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px #ffffff,0 0 30px #008000,0 0 6px #0000ff;
  }
  20%,21.999%,63%,63.999%,65%,69.999% {
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes lower {
  0%,12%,18.999%,23%,31.999%,37%,44.999%,46%,49.999%,51%,58.999%,61%,68.999%,71%,85.999%,96%,100% {
    opacity:0.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
  }
  19%,22.99%,32%,36.999%,45%,45.999%,50%,50.99%,59%,60.999%,69%,70.999%,86%,95.999% { 
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}

@keyframes upper {
  0%,19.999%,22%,62.999%,64%, 64.999%,70%,100% {
    opacity:.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px #ffffff,0 0 30px #008000,0 0 6px #0000ff;
  }
  20%,21.999%,63%,63.999%,65%,69.999% {
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}
@keyframes lower {
  0%,12%,18.999%,23%,31.999%,37%,44.999%,46%,49.999%,51%,58.999%,61%,68.999%,71%,85.999%,96%,100% {
    opacity:0.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
  }
  19%,22.99%,32%,36.999%,45%,45.999%,50%,50.99%,59%,60.999%,69%,70.999%,86%,95.999% { 
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}
```

The reason your code works on Codepen is because Codepen uses [prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) by default.

Demo...

```css
body { background-color: #111111; }
div {
  padding: 40px;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
  color: red;
}
div p { margin:0; }
#error:hover { text-shadow: 0 0 200px #ffffff,0 0 80px #008000,0 0 6px #0000ff; }
#code:hover { text-shadow: 0 0 100px red,0 0 40px FireBrick,0 0 8px DarkRed; }
#error {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 80px #ffffff,0 0 30px #008000,0 0 6px #0000ff;
}
#error span {
  -webkit-animation: upper 11s linear infinite;
  animation: upper 11s linear infinite;
}
#code span:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation: lower 10s linear infinite;
  animation: lower 10s linear infinite;
}
#code span:nth-of-type(1) {
  text-shadow: none;
  opacity:.4;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upper {
  0%,19.999%,22%,62.999%,64%, 64.999%,70%,100% {
    opacity:.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px #ffffff,0 0 30px #008000,0 0 6px #0000ff;
  }
  20%,21.999%,63%,63.999%,65%,69.999% {
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes lower {
  0%,12%,18.999%,23%,31.999%,37%,44.999%,46%,49.999%,51%,58.999%,61%,68.999%,71%,85.999%,96%,100% {
    opacity:0.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
  }
  19%,22.99%,32%,36.999%,45%,45.999%,50%,50.99%,59%,60.999%,69%,70.999%,86%,95.999% { 
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}

@keyframes upper {
  0%,19.999%,22%,62.999%,64%, 64.999%,70%,100% {
    opacity:.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px #ffffff,0 0 30px #008000,0 0 6px #0000ff;
  }
  20%,21.999%,63%,63.999%,65%,69.999% {
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}
@keyframes lower {
  0%,12%,18.999%,23%,31.999%,37%,44.999%,46%,49.999%,51%,58.999%,61%,68.999%,71%,85.999%,96%,100% {
    opacity:0.99; text-shadow: 0 0 80px red,0 0 30px FireBrick,0 0 6px DarkRed;
  }
  19%,22.99%,32%,36.999%,45%,45.999%,50%,50.99%,59%,60.999%,69%,70.999%,86%,95.999% { 
    opacity:0.4; text-shadow: none; 
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div>
  <p id="error">E<span>r</span>ror</p>
  <p id="code">4<span>0</span><span>4</span></p>
</div>
```